# Appdata in Non-Windows

Tags: java, linux, persistence, appdata

To access the Appdata folder in Windows, I can just use `%APPDATA%` in the path name and that's it.

Does this method work on Linux and other OS as well? I know there alternatives to using `%APPDATA%`, but my question is just if I can use it there, and how the path name is translated.

Comment: There's no direct equivalent to AppData, no, unless you count the home directory - typically you'd just store your settings in a ".whatever" child path of the home directory. Linux has no equivalent of Window's local / roaming / locallow split either.

Comment: This works fine for me:

 `public static String getAppdataDir() {
  String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
  if (os.toLowerCase().contains("windows")) {
   return System.getenv("APPDATA");
  } else {
   return System.getProperty("user.home");
  }
 }`

Comment: What type of app. is it?  E.G. desktop app., applet, web-app. ..

Comment: Hmm, note then that the conventions what you put in that directory are different on the different OSes though - you want more than that really.

Comment: It's a desktop app. Also, I got methods for using ".dirname" on Linux and Other and "Dirname" on Windows, so it should be alright. Don't know about Mac. These directories are for settings and profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%APPDATA%` is a windows only shortcut. The Mac equivalent is usually `~/Library/Application Support`, but user specific information is in `~\Library\Preferences` and the linux equivalent depends on the specific application. For instance, Chrome data is usually in `~\.Chrome` for linux.

Comment: And what would happen if I'd have code creating a file "%APPDATA%/Subfolder/file.txt" with this exact path under Linux?

Comment: It would most likely throw a `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Wrap it with an OS check so that it only executes if it's on windows, I use `String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");` and then check if osName contains `Windows` by doing something like `if(osName.toLowerCase().contains("windows"){ //blablabla}`

Comment: Okay, so it seems I finally have to include this wrapper thing. Thanks :)